How to link to my app in expo react native with
How can I create a link that links to my login screen in expo react native from the browser. I see this from the docs, but I'm struggling to understand how to implement it. What I've done so far is adding the below in my app.json file.
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "myapp"
  }
}

